# After converting from C# to vb.net it shows an error

Tags: c#, vb.net, json-rpc, code-conversion

I am trying to convert C# code to Visual Basic.

This is the C# code:

```cs
public static string RequestServer1(string methodName, List<string> parameters)
{
    return RequestServer(methodName, parameters.Select(p => new JValue(p)).ToList<JToken>());
}
```

And this is the VB.Net code:

```vb
Public Shared Function RequestServer(ByVal methodName As String, ByVal parameters As List(Of String)) As String
    Return RequestServer(methodName, parameters.Select(Function(p) New JValue(p)).ToList())
End Function
```

And here the function with `List(Of JToken)`:

```vb
Public Shared Function RequestServer(ByVal methodName As String, ByVal parameters As List(Of JToken)) As JToken
    Dim ServerIp As String = "http://localhost:8332"
    Dim UserName As String = "hama"
    Dim Password As String = "hama"
    Dim webRequest As HttpWebRequest = CType(webRequest.Create(ServerIp), HttpWebRequest)
    webRequest.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(UserName, Password)

    webRequest.ContentType = "application/json-rpc"
    webRequest.Method = "POST"

    Dim respVal As String = String.Empty
    Dim joe As JObject = New JObject
    joe.Add(New JProperty("jsonrpc", 1))
    joe.Add(New JProperty("id", 1))
    joe.Add(New JProperty("method", methodName))
    Dim props As JArray = New JArray
    For Each parameter In parameters
        props.Add(parameter)
    Next
    joe.Add(New JProperty("params", props))
    ' serialize json for the request
    Dim s As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(joe)
    Dim byteArray() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s)
    webRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
    Dim dataStream As Stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
    dataStream.Close()
    Dim streamReader As StreamReader = Nothing
    Try
        Dim webResponse As WebResponse = webRequest.GetResponse
        streamReader = New StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream, True)
        respVal = streamReader.ReadToEnd
        Dim data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(respVal).ToString
        Return data
    Catch exp As Exception

    Finally
        If (Not (streamReader) Is Nothing) Then
            streamReader.Close()
        End If
    End Try

    Return String.Empty
End Function
```

Sometimes I need a list of `JToken`, and sometimes I need a list of string, so my both methods can work.

Before compile it shows an error, it doesn't accept `Return RequestServer(methodName, parameters.Select(Function(p) New JValue(p)).ToList())`

It says:

> Impossible to convert a List (Of JValue) to a List (Of String)

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: It is important to share the complete error details.

Comment: @Crowcoder it Says ` impossible to convert a list of JValue to a list of String`

Comment: The C# code was converting a `List(Of JValue)` to a `List(of JToken)`, but this conversion was lost in the translation of C# to VB.

Comment: I'm not sure if `JValue` inherits `JToken`, but if it does, try `Return RequestServer(methodName, parameters.Select(Function(p) New JValue(p)).Cast(Of JToken)().ToList())`

Comment: @SeanSkelly That's great, please put it as an answer so i mark it, thank you

Comment: The direct VB equivalent of the C# `.ToList<JToken>()` would be `.ToList(Of JToken)()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C# code was converting a `List(Of JValue)` to a `List(of JToken)`, but this conversion was lost in the translation of C# to VB.

If JValue inherits JToken, then you can use [Enumerable.Cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast) to cast your enumerable from one type to another (before calling .ToList()):

```
Public Shared Function RequestServer(ByVal methodName As String, ByVal parameters As List(Of String)) As String
    Return RequestServer(methodName, parameters.Select(Function(p) New JValue(p)).Cast(Of JToken).ToList())
End Function
```